# Android use custom model

Tags: java, android

Ive created a new model in app.java called Group like :

```
public class Group {
String _id;
String creator;
String name;

 public Group(String _id, String creator, String name) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.name = creator;
    this.name = name;
 }
}
```

Now in my MainActivity.java file i want to use this model.

How can i refer to this model so im able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MainActivity class will be able to access the Group class
if your Group class belongs to the same package as your MainActivity class.

Or you can also make the Group class as inner class of your MainActivity so
that it will readily visible inside your MainActivity.

Make sure you Group class has a package declaration like:

```
package com.example.app;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Group group = new Group("id", "creator", "name");
```

Comment: the problem is It doesnt recognice the custom model, i guess i have to refer to the file somewhere.

Comment: You need to import the model class

Comment: thats exactly what im asking, How can i refer to this model so im able to use it.ive tried : import app.java.User import java.User

Comment: What package is the Group model located in?

Comment: ive added it to the app.java folder

Comment: `import app.java.Group;`